# fatfreeframework using order by and the $option argument

Tags: sql-order-by, fat-free-framework

I have looked high and low for an example of doing this and can't figure it out. The API reference page shows this

```
array(
    'order' => string $orderClause,
    'group' => string $groupClause,
    'limit' => integer $limit,
    'offset' => integer $offset
    )
```

but how on earth do I implement this in code. I have tried the following but it does not work. I love fat free but sometimes the docs feel a little light weight.

```
$this->load(array('reportname=? ', $reportname, 'order' => 'rundate desc', 'limit' => 1));
```

Answer (score 2):

I stared and stared at the docs and figured this out. Hope it helps someone else out.

```php
$this->load(
  array('reportname=? ', $reportname),
  array( 'order' => 'rundate desc', 'limit' => 1)
);
```